# Convert json into mysql database?

Tags: android, json, database, android-activity, phpmyadmin

Can we convert json format data coming from server into mysql database or means can we store

the data coming through json into mysql database.

Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Although not a 'yes' in the sense that you can just shove a JSON string at MySQL and have it insert the data itself, yes, you can programmatically take a JSON string, parse it, and insert that data into a MySQL database. You may want to look at something like [JSON-to-MySQL](https://github.com/adamwulf/json-to-mysql), which is a set of PHP scripts that can take arbitrary JSON data and convert it to SQL data.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way is parser you Json data to Object and store it in database.

I recommend you use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/), see [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/) and [here](http://www.journaldev.com/2324/jackson-json-processing-api-in-java-example-tutorial) a simple example.

Hope its help